# AngularJS Display Time in PDT/PST

Tags: angularjs

Using [ng-model-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions) or the [date](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) is it possible to set a timezone to automatically adjust for daylight savings time (i.e. switch between PST and PDT based on the value)?

For example:

```
<input type="date" ng-model="order.scheduled" ng-model-options="{ timezone: 'PST' }" />
<input type="time" ng-model="order.scheduled" ng-model-options="{ timezone: 'PST' }" />
```

Only works when the time falls into standard time (not daylight time).

Comment: For working with dates and times I highly recommend looking at [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/) and its companion [angular-moment](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment). MomentJS has an isDST() method along with various UTC and time zone functions.

Comment: @Lex I can use MomentJS for the display of dates - but what about the input?

Comment: Sorry, I'm probably being thick, but what are you asking? How to present an input to the user for selecting a date and time? There are various date/time-picker controls available out there depending on what UI framework you're using.

Comment: @Lex correct. I'm using the browser based inputs (type='date' and type='time'). I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need moment.tz and a helper function here. Odd that this isn't built into Angular:

```
// eg. getOffset(new Date, 'America/Los_Angeles') => '-0700'
// (date: Date, timezone: String): String
scope.getOffset = function (date, timezone) {
  return moment
    .tz(date, timezone)
    .format('Z')
    .replace(':', '')
}

...
<input
  type="time"
  ng-model="order.scheduled"
  ng-model-options="{
    timezone: getOffset(order.scheduled, 'America/Los_Angeles')
  }"
/>
```

Comment: darn - unfortunately AngularJS doesn't reload the ng-model-options dynamically.

Comment: [You're right](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngModel.js#L1303) - bummer. Looks like you'll either need to re-render the input every time the date or timezone changes, or move the timezone-awareness to your app layer (instead of making the input[time] directive timezone-aware). The latter seems like a less intrusive way to do it.